# Drawing additional control nodes for selected arc of a node?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am drawing arcs around a node that show portions of linked data. The arcs are representing that data. To get some interaction, I like to add an additional svg element for a selected arc to interact on click events in that additional element with the user.

My previous trials to add elements to the svg directly without data bound (d3 nodes) seemed to work, but get crappy when another function clears out the data to start over with a fresh and clean area.

So I think, I have to hook it anyhow into this function:

function redraw_arcs(tool_menu) {
    if (node == null) return;

```
paths = node.selectAll("path").data(function (d, i) {
    if (d.proportions == undefined) {
        d.proportions = Array();
    }

    return pie(d.proportions);
});

paths.enter().append("svg:path")
     .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
        return d.data.arc_color_org;
      })
      .attr("d", arc);

// Draw the svg for one arc only...

paths.exit().remove();
```

}

How do I add this selective item?

I think anything using

```
paths
  .classed("node_selected", function (d) { return d === selected_arc; })
  .append("foo")
  ...
```

It may also be too complicated and a better choice would be html layered over the complete diagram. What do you think?

Thanks,

Lothar

Comment: It sounds like you're having trouble with manually-added elements being selected and then matched by data when they shouldn't be. To prevent this, assign a special class to the elements you do want to match to the data and select accordingly, e.g. `node.selectAll("path.node")`.

Comment: I do this: this.svg_tool = svg.selectAll(".ToolMenu").data([this.nodeHook]); and when removing, this: this.svg_tool.remove(); Something get wrong at a later step. I also assume some select mismatch. The nodeHook is the arc I have selected. But the arc is bound to a member of a node, thus belongs to the node. The arc itself did not have an explicit data element.